# Computing dimension of a projective cone

Tags: algebraic-geometry

From a exercise on Shafarevich:

Let $L \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a $n-1$- dimensional linear subspace, $X \subset L$ an irreducible closed variety and $y$ a point in ${P}^n \setminus L$. Join $y$ to all points $x \in X$ by lines, and denote by $Y$ the set of points lying on all these lines, that is, the cone over $X$ with vertex $y$. Prove that $Y$ is an irreducible projective variety and $\dim Y = \dim X + 1$

**My attempt** $Y$ cannot be reducible because all its irreducible components would have the point $y$ in common, so their union could not be disjoint. To prove that $\dim Y \geq \dim X +1$, let $X_0 \subset .... \subset X_n \subset X$ a strictly ascending chain of irreducible closed sets in $X$. Then $\left\{ y \right\} \subset Y_0 ... \subset Y_n \subset Y$ is another ascending chain where $Y_i$ is the cone of vertex $y$ constructed on $X_i$. So, it is proved that $\dim Y \geq \dim X +1$. How should I prove the inverse? And also, should I prove that $Y$ is a projective variety, so the set of all common zeros of a number of homogeneous polynomials?

Comment: I've improved your MathJax. In the future, please put all relevant text inside math mode and use the appropriate commands like \dim to format $\dim$ and the like.

Comment: Do you know the dimension of fibers theorem? The rational map $Y \dashrightarrow X$ becomes regular after deleting ${y}$, at which point you have a map with $1$-dimensional fibers, and I think that theorem gives the inequality in the correct direction.

Comment: Yes, it is very likely that theorem could help, because this exercise is in the section right after it. I still don't see how I could apply it though, I'm a beginner in the subject. Could you please be more specific? Thank you